# How can I load/update geocodes from a SQL database and mark them on a map?

Tags: google-maps, coldfusion, google-fusion-tables

I have a google map I am trying to create that will show all of our clubs located around the world, currently we have a couple thousand clubs. I have a map that I created using a fusion table which is displayed [here](http://www.optimist.org/clublocmap.cfm).

The issue I am having is with updating this map when new clubs are entered, which as of now the only way I see is to pull the database with the new info and create a new map which is not ideal.I would like for it to update when the data base is updated, or set up a spot where an authorized user could add a marker. I have looked at using other layer programs, but no luck.

**Additional Info:**

It looks like the data is loaded via

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col20",
    from: "1aLeInM9ohpOSbF8422tYyVx-bsbYfjsiQZXgpXE",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Are new clubs entered often enough that you don't want to refresh the page? You could have an Ajax process poll the DB for data every so often or you could use websockets (only for newer browsers).

Comment: Why do you believe that map won't update when a new club is added?  It might take 20 minutes to an hour (however long google caches the tiles for) for an updated location to appear, is that not adequate?

Comment: Did you know that you may store data in a FusionTable with serverside requests? https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#insertRow

Comment: Thank You  for the quick replies. I have seen that, but am not sure how to work that with my code. The insert would have to be entered alongside with when the user enters the data to the database I suppose. Also the csv file I upload to the fusion table is a combination of database table not sure how that will effect it.

Comment: I am still stuck on how to update and insert new info into my fusion table from my webpage, but from what I have seen above this is possible. the other problem I see is updating the map geocodes without going into the google drive and loading them to the map. Thanks.